# ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre new Objeto() y new Objeto?

Tags: c++, punteros, objeto

Tengo estos códigos, la única diferencia es que uno tiene new Ganado() y otro new Ganado. Hasta donde entiendo hacen lo mismo y ambos me compilan. Me surge la pregunta, ¿qué diferencia tiene el ponerle los paréntesis o no ponérselos? ¿Uno no debería correr pero me lo permite el compilador? O hay alguna diferencia técnica

```
class Ganado{
public:
Ganado(){}
Ganado(int a){}
};

int main(){
   Ganado *ganado[2];
   for (int i=0;i<2;i++)
   {
      ganado[i] = new Ganado;
   }
}
```

El segundo:

```
class Ganado{
public:
Ganado(){}
Ganado(int a){}
};

int main(){
   Ganado *ganado[2];
   for (int i=0;i<2;i++)
   {
      ganado[i] = new Ganado();
   }
}
```

Comment: La diferencia es que una version puede recibir parametros, la otra por no tener parentesis no los puede tener, a nivel de funcionalidad no cambia nada y todo sigue funcionando igual, simplemente es una acortacion que existe en muchos lenguajes de programacion para no tener que escribir parentesis si es que el objeto no requiere parametros, en javascript por ejemplo esta notacion tambien existe.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> ¿qué diferencia tiene el ponerle los paréntesis o no ponérselos?

La única diferencia es que al usar paréntesis puedes pasarle parámetros al constructor.

Pero si vas a usar, como es el caso, el constructor por defecto, puedes usar cualquiera de las dos opciones indistintamente ya que su efecto es **exactamente** el mismo.

En cualquier caso, nada mejor que verlo con un ejemplo:

```
class POO
{
  int valor = 5;
};

POO* func1()
{
    return new POO;
}

POO* func2()
{
    return new POO();
}
```

Este código genera el siguiente ensamblado usando gcc 10.1:

```
func1():
    sub     rsp, 8
    mov     edi, 4
    call    operator new(unsigned long)
    mov     DWORD PTR [rax], 5
    add     rsp, 8
    ret
func2():
    sub     rsp, 8
    mov     edi, 4
    call    operator new(unsigned long)
    mov     DWORD PTR [rax], 5
    add     rsp, 8
    ret
```

Como puedes ver, ambas funciones generan exactamente las mismas instrucciones en ensamblador. Puedes ver el ejemplo funcionando [aquí](https://godbolt.org/z/kb_WB6)

Answer (score 4):

> ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre new Objeto() y new Objeto?

Ninguna, tanto `new Objeto();` como `new Objeto;` llaman al constructor por defecto del objeto. Eso significa que sólo puede usarse sobre objetos que tengan dicho constructor accesible:

```
struct A {};                 // new A; y new A(); funcionan.
struct B { B() {} };         // new B; y new B(); funcionan.
struct C { C() = default; }; // new C; y new C(); funcionan.

class D {};                 // error, el constructor es privado.
class E { E() {} };         // error, el constructor es privado.
class F { F() = default; }; // error, el constructor es privado.
```

Observa que cuando no se define constructor, se creará un constructor por defecto (casos `A` y `D`), este constructor por defecto estará inhabilitado o no existirá si existe un constructor con parámetros o alguno de los miembros del objeto no es construible por defecto:

```
// new G; y new G(); no funcionan porque el constructor no recibe parámetro.
struct G { G(int) {} };
// new H; y new H(); no funcionan porque G no es construible por defecto.
struct H { G g; };
```

Unos ejemplos más, con casos "*raros*":

```
class I { friend class J; }; // error, el constructor es privado.
class J { I i; };            // new J; y new J(); funcionan porque J puede construir I.

// new K; y new K(); funcionan porque el constructor tiene parámetro por defecto.
struct K { K(int = 0) {} };
```

Puedes ver todos los casos en <kbd>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jVBLTsMwEF3XpxiJTSJBy95ikYQmpUViy9ZNJ8hSagfHAaGKw3AWDhbGxDaoagVePc34/abuuqu6FeppHHtrhtpCBod3DsdvsQCFr5BxeJtAknJoBlVLrYSaM0/O4QB5kpIE/BLx5DyQ89PkgsgFkW9gh40YWsudiCcXgVwckRnF73u4PRcbjdHmErCFWqvJSRvAHjojX8ROz73AktyXp6L/V6AkgfJU/L8FwgUqkqgSqWyI4ctXoXzlyiv90x86bZ4HdDODtdwidMJ8fuzRGh0Pu3Ky8MRjMS@7CrKrc7KVm1JSH1xuW3Qr1xCpRbz@HTk0RqLawTRYOzO/XNPyDuT3JETa0GzjmtK5rn1bxi5IVyoEi71NHmkMYrAaBH1yMR85GbdoEQSfNtuwcQX8bktGjC0WQazM7u8fGHNeeyFVkrIDm307ZCn3KI@oiGgd0SZ12WRDgl5tmt/GH8uIyoiqiFYpn7ELOo5sGJsZtINRcM3Z@zh@AQ)</kbd>.